# Using 'void' template arguments in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function

Take the following minimal example:

```
using Type1 = std::function<void(void)>;

template <typename T>
using Type2 = std::function<void(T)>;

Type1 whyDoesThisWork;
Type2<void> andYetThisDoesNot;
```

If the second type alias, I get the error "Argument may not have 'void' type". (I tested with Xcode 4.5, Clang/c++11/libc++, OS X 10.7.)

I find this curious: I would have expected `Type1` and `Type2<void>` to behave identically. What's going on here? And is there a way to rewrite the second type alias so I *can* write `Type2<void>` and get `std::function<void(void)>` instead of an error?

**Edit** I should probably add that the reason I want this is to allow for something like the following:

```
template <typename ... T>
using Continuation = std::function<void(T...)>;

auto someFunc = []() -> void {
  printf("I'm returning void!\n");
};

Continuation<decltype(someFunc())> c;
```

`Continuation<decltype(someFunc())>` becomes `Continuation<void>` and I get the error.

Comment: Hehe, it works the other way round (`T(void)`)...

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that `void(void)` is just a courtesy compatibility notation for `void()`, but `void` isn't actually a valid argument type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is "templates are not string substitution".  `void f(void)` has meaning only so far as it is an alias for `void f()` in C++, in order to be backwards compatible with C.

The first step is to use variadics, as noted elsewhere.

The second step is figuring out how to map `void` returning functions to ... well, maybe something like `std::function<void()>`, or maybe something else.  I say maybe something else because unlike the other cases, you cannot call `std::function<void()> foo; foo( []()->void {} );` -- it isn't a true continuation.

Something like this maybe:

```
template<typename T>
struct Continuation
{
  typedef std::function<void(T)> type;
};

template<>
struct Continuation<void>
{
  typedef std::function<void()> type;
};
```

then use it like this:

```
auto someFunc = []()->void {};
Continuation<decltype(someFunc())>::type c;
```

which gives you the type you want.  You could even add in an apply to continuation:

```
template<typename T>
struct Continuation
{
  typedef std::function<void(T)> type;

  template<typename func, typename... Args>
  static void Apply( type const& cont, func&& f, Args... args)
  {
    cont( f(args...) );
  }
};

template<>
struct Continuation<void>
{
  typedef std::function<void()> type;
  template<typename func, typename... Args>
  static void Apply( type const& cont, func&& f, Args... args)
  {
    f(args...);
    cont();
  }
};
```

which lets you apply a continuation to an execution of a function uniformly if the incoming type is a void or if it is a non-void type.

However, I would ask "why would you want to do this"?

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. _Why_ would I want do do this? I'm trying to implement a simple version of Futures from Microsoft's [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963556.aspx). A continuation receives as arguments the return values of the tasks it depends on.

Answer (score 15):

I don't have an actual answer, only what I said in the comment: You can't have `void` as a function type, as in:

```
int foo(int, char, void, bool, void, void);     // nonsense!
```

I believe that `T(void)` is only allowed as a compatibility notation for C (which distinguishes *declarations* and *prototypes*, very differently from C++, and which needs to be able to say "no arguments").

So, the solution should be variadic:

```
template <typename ...Args> using myType = std::function<void(Args...)>;
```

That way you can properly have *no arguments*:

```
myType<> f = []() { std::cout << "Boo\n"; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I somehow managed to down-vote this by accident and didn't notice until after it was too late to change it.

Answer (score 9):

Several answers already explain the rationale.  To add to those answers, the specification says (C++11 §8.3.5[dcl.func]/4):

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type `void` is
>   equivalent to an empty parameter list. Except for this special case, a parameter shall not have type *cv* `void`.

In your `Type2` example, the `T` in `void(T)` is a *dependent type*--it depends on a template parameter.

Comment: This also means that non-dependent types like `void(typename std::type_identity<void>::type)` and `void(std::void_t<T>)` also work which is strange

Answer (score 3):

When a function is declared to take a parameter of type `void`, as in `std::function<void(void)>`, that is really just a goofy way of saying that it takes zero parameters. But the way you've declared Type2 is as a `std::function` with a signature that returns nothing (void), but that takes 1 parameter.  void is not a type that can be used as a parameter, it is just a way of declaring that there are no parameters.  So it doesn't work with Type2, because that requires an actual type that can be used as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Void can be interpreted as an empty parameter if you pass it to a function. You're not using a void pointer after all so

```
void func (void)
```

becomes

```
void func ()
```