# How to make std::function<void(Arg)> compile, when typename Arg = void?

Tags: c++11, gcc

Let's say I have a type alias like this:

```
template <typename Arg>
using Func = std::function<void(Arg)>;
```

It works fine except for the case when Arg is void:

```
Func<int> f1;
Func<void> f2; // doesn't compile
```

The second one gives the following compilation error:

```
error: invalid parameter type ‘void’using Func = std::function<void(Arg)>;
error: in declaration ‘using Func = class std::function<void(Arg)>’
```

How can I make it work to create alias for `std::function<void()>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add some template specializations:

```
template<typename T>
struct FuncImpl
{
    using type = std::function<void(T)>;
};

template<>
struct FuncImpl<void>
{
    using type = std::function<void()>;
};

template <typename Arg>
using Func = typename FuncImpl<Arg>::type;
```

[**EXAMPLE**](https://godbolt.org/g/gH6ugo)

Comment: Thanks! It does the trick (answer accepted) but is there an explanation ?

Comment: @AlexandreA. Hm, I have just done some search and seems that the question is dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372173/using-void-template-arguments-in-c. Unfortunately, I checked it after I had posted the answer :(

Comment: Indeed but thanks anyway to pointing out the right direction!