# Is foo(void) equivalent to foo() in a template context?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

For C legacy reasons, the following definitions in C++ are equivalent:

```
void foo() {}
void foo(void) {}
```

What happens when foo is in a templated class ? For example:

```
template <typename T> struct C { void foo(T) {} };

int main()
{ C<void> c;
  c.foo();
}
```

MSVC (19.30) accepts this code, but gcc (11.2) rejects it.
It seems that compilers disagree as to whether `foo(T)` is equivalent to `foo()` when `T = void`.

Which is correct ?

Comment: I think the `void` as a template argument is invalid. Possible duplicate: [Using 'void' template arguments in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13372173/10871073) - but things *may* have changed in Standards released since that question/answer was posted (over 9 years ago). The C++11 Standard is quoted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372928/10871073)

Comment: Also maybe relevant: [How can an incomplete type be used as a template parameter to vector here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31345193/10871073) And, from the Standard: *A type cv void is an incomplete type that cannot be completed;*

Comment: `void` is definitely allowed as a class template argument, and there is plenty of code that uses that. A non-template function declaration with a (single) `void` parameter type is also allowed, but is synonymous with an empty parameter list.  The issue is whether the `void` is allowed as a function parameter type when `void` is not present literally as a keyword, but is the value of a template argument.

Comment: OK. I was imprecise. I meant `void` is not allowed as a templated argument type (I think).

Comment: The excerpt from the C++11 Standard in the *answer* I linked in my first comment (by James McNellis) seems to cover your case completely. Your `void` argument is **not** non-dependent. I really can't see how that answer does not answer this question, so I'm closing this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

The specification says (C++11 §8.3.5[dcl.func]/4):

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of **non-dependent type** void is equivalent to an empty parameter list. Except for this special case, a parameter shall not have type cv void.

And since in your case you have a **dependent type**(depending on `T`), gcc is correct.

Comment: So, if I understand the comments correctly, the answer to the original question seems to be that gcc correctly rejected the code.

Comment: @user1958486 Yes gcc is correct.